# Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity3d

Портирую игру с iOS на Android. При билде выдает ошибку. Пробовал билдить пустой проект, так всё ок.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>      D:\Androidsdk\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "D:/Androidsdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:android.support.v4:android.support.v4 -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-8.4.0\res" -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.4.0\res" -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-8.4.0\res" -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.4.0\res" -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res" -S "D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.2.0\res"

Comment: Может код ошибки выложишь, а не тонну ключей с путями. Он там ниже идет.

Comment: stderr[
D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-8.4.0\res\values\common_attrs.xml:13: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
D:\tradingprototype\tradingprototype\TradingPrototype\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.4.0\res\values\values.xml:3: Original attribute defined here.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему удалением плагинов с низкой версией. Удалил support-v4